# Find color with tolerance in bufferedimage

Tags: java, colors, awt, rgb, awtrobot

I'm writing a method that will attempt to find a color in a bufferedImage. At the moment, the method works by taking a screencap, and then scanning the image for a specific color. Now I'd like to add some RGB tolerence, so if the user is trying to find color (1, 3, 5) with tolerance 1, any color +-1 R, B or G will return true.

I could solve this by first generating a arrayList of RGB values that work, and then for each pixel I could go through the array and check with each value. The problem is that would probably get VERY slow for high tolerances on large images.

Is there a more efficient or possibly a built in way I can do this? Here is my method as it stands right now. Thank you!

```
public static Point findColor(Box searchArea, int color){
    System.out.println("Test");
    BufferedImage image = generateScreenCap(searchArea);
    for (int i = 0; i < image.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.getHeight(); j++) {
            if((image.getRGB(i, j)*-1)==color){
                return new Point(i + searchArea.x1, j + searchArea.y1);
            }
        }
    }
    return new Point(-1, -1);
}
```

Edit: I'm using the int RGB values for all comparisons, so instead of Color[1, 1, 1], I use Color.getRGB() which returns a negative int which I convert to positive for end user simplicity.

Comment: Why it will be slow for high tolerances on large images?

Comment: @ForguesR In a 800x600 image, thats 480 000 pixels that need to be checked. Checking for 1 color in each of those pixels is ok, the speed is fine, but imagine checking for 100 different colors in each of 480 000 pixels, all of a sudden its 100x slower. Efficiency is a huge priority in this project, so if theres a way to do this faster that would be awesome

Comment: You are comparing your RGB value as a "whole" with a int which is, I guess, the color you are looking for.  Why don't you compare the RGB values instead?

Comment: @ForguesR Yeah I guess thats sort of what I'm looking for I guess, like a quick way to look for any color with [R, G, B] of [x+-tolerance, y+-tolerance, z+-tolerance]. Is my best bet just to use for loops to compare `Color`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare RGB values and not the "whole" color if you want to have a custom tolerance.  Here is the code, it is not tested, but you get the idea :

```
public static Point findColor(Box searchArea, int r, int g, int b, int tolerance) {
    // Pre-calc RGB "tolerance" values out of the loop (min is 0 and max is 255)
    int minR = Math.max(r - tolerance, 0);
    int minG = Math.max(g - tolerance, 0);
    int minB = Math.max(b - tolerance, 0);
    int maxR = Math.min(r + tolerance, 255);
    int maxG = Math.min(g + tolerance, 255);
    int maxB = Math.min(b + tolerance, 255);

    BufferedImage image = generateScreenCap(searchArea);
    for (int i = 0; i < image.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.getHeight(); j++) {
            // get single RGB pixel
            int color = image.getRGB(i, j);

            // get individual RGB values of that pixel
            // (could use Java's Color class but this is probably a little faster)
            int red = (color >> 16) & 0x000000FF;
            int green = (color >> 8) & 0x000000FF;
            int blue = (color) & 0x000000FF;  

            if ( (red >= minR && red <= maxR) &&
                 (green >= minG && green <= maxG) &&
                 (blue >= minB && blue <= maxB) ) 
                return new Point(i + searchArea.x1, j + searchArea.y1);
        }
    }
    return new Point(-1, -1);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, but I get the idea, I should be able to shape and mould the method to get it to do what I want. Thank yoU!

Comment: Glad I could help. Can you tell me what doesn't work?

Comment: Right now when searching a color that doesn't exist in my sample I'm getting 0 returned, so the very first check is passing even though my searched color doesn't exist

Comment: I'm troubleshooting it right now though, hopefully its a small issue

Comment: Great!  Give me feedback when you find the problem so I can fix my answer if needed.

Comment: Ok so the problem is minR will always be 0, maxR will always be 255, and red will always be between.

Comment: Math.min's should me .max's, and the other way around for Math.max I believe, let me check

Comment: I THINK thats right, I'm still getting wrong readings somewhere but it could me another method in my library.

Comment: Ok yeah that's correct, swicth Math.min and Math.max

Comment: Fixed, sorry for that mistake!